# Does Java Program on XP will run as it is on windows 7

Tags: java

I wanted to know Will the Java desktop application running on Windows XP also run as it is on Windows 7 or need any modification in program?

Comment: Unless you are using any *OS specific* features, you are good to go. BTW, you should also checkthe compatibility of your java versions.

Comment: It almost certainly will work (you'll need to install a suitable Java runtime on the Windows 7 box).

Comment: Is it pure Java or does it use native code as well?

Comment: What makes you think otherwise? It might depend on the respective version of the Java runtime, however.

Comment: Java is platform independent

Comment: Hi I want to find some scenarioes like native calls have been made, or direct interface
with 3rd party application which is getting migrated due to OS upgrade etc

Comment: Also for java application what aspects are tied down to the OS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theoretically java is platform independent and should run on any Windows, any linux, any mac etc without any modification exactly the same. Practically you have to check that you do not use any platform dependent features or parameters.

For example:

1. JNI
2. Execution of platform specific command line tools
3. Platform specific file paths
4. Communication with platform specific processes/services
5. Operations that can produce security issues on some Operating systems (e.g. specific file paths, registry entries under `HKLM` on windows 7,8 etc)
6. Assumptions about line, path, file path separators (`\r\n` vs `\n`, `\` vs '/', `;` vs `:`)
7. Wrong usage of layout managers that can cause UI to fail on some screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks AlexR .. Can you please suggest on some scenarioes for java application what aspects are tied down to the OS , programming aspect

Comment: I think that I already enumerated them. However if you want more assistance could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will definitely work. Try it and if got any errors send us for review.

Comment: please change definitely to in most cases or something like that! in some cases(like what AlexR said) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Java is Platform Independent.**

You can use that application in any OS.

In stand alone application, Java **source code** is converted into **byte code** .  So Java is platform independent.

Comment: Hi I want to find some scenarioes like native calls have been made, or direct interface with 3rd party application which is getting migrated due to OS upgrade etc –  user3652391 2 mins ago   edit   
     
Also for java application what aspects are tied down to the OS –

Answer (score 0):

Java's claim is to be a [WORA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) (Write Once, Run Anywhere) language.

Assuming that Windows 7's JRE hasn't introduced any new bugs and assuming your code is straight-forward Java that doesn't rely on JNI, manipulating Windows XP specific registry keys, etc., the answer is a definite **yes**. It should run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks for the **JVM** (Java Virtual Machine) it will act the same on different platforms ...